# If else statement with three conditions using Application.Match to find row number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro which imports a lot of .csv files from a folder with many subfolders. This is working so far. 
Now I want to implement that if a file was already imported it should not be imported a second time. There I get into an issue.

I really tried to find a solution with the search function, but I only could find "If else statement with two conditions" but it didn't get my code working.

I need to write an if else statement with three conditions.

Conditions: Only if the file name (column C) the folder name (column B) and the parent folder name (Column A) are an exact match, the file is NOT to be imported.

For one Condition it is working fine.

This is my code snippet for finding the file name in column C:

```
 ' Check if file was already imported should return Row Number --> SearchColumn

If Not IsError(Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFile.name), Columns("C:C"), 0)) Then
   SearchColumn = Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFile.name), Columns("C:C"), 0)
End If
```

The variable `SearchColumn` tells my where it found the file name, if it is in the list. I want to use this variable to check if in the same row in column B and column A are matching to the names of the file.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
' Check if file was already imported should return Row Number --> SearchColumn

If Not IsError(Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFile.name), Columns("C:C"), 0)) Then
   SearchColumn = Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFile.name), Columns("C:C"), 0)
End If

If Not IsError(Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFile.name), Columns("C:C"), 0)) _
   And Not IsError(Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(oFolder), "B1:B" & SearchColumn, 0)) _
   And Not IsError(Application.Match(fso.GetBaseName(folderName), "A1:A" & SearchColumn, 0)) Then

' Do nothing because file was already imported

Else

' import file / copy content

Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(oFile.path)
  'some more macro code
```

But somehow it ignores both of the other conditions. Where am I mistaken?

Best TMC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out by myself. Actually it was pretty simple.
Since the code was working with one condition very well, I just concatenated the conditions to one. I concatenated the string in columns `C`, `B` and `A` in a new column `E` (--> C & B & A).

```
Range("E" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = fso.GetBaseName(Left(oFolder, InStrRev(oFolder, "\"))) _
                                    & fso.GetBaseName(oFolder) _
                                    & fso.GetBaseName(FileName)
```

I used this column to look for my concatenated criteria like this:

```
 If Not IsError(Application.Match(criteria, Columns("E:E"), 0)) Then

    ' Do nothing because file was already imported

 Else

    'import code
```

That was it.

Best TMC